# Eclipse External tools cannot start Meteorite: uname: command not found, even when PATH is set

Tags: eclipse, meteor

In Terminal everything is working just fine:

```
alex@ubuntu:~/workspace/spt$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/meteor/bin
alex@ubuntu:~/workspace/spt$ mrt

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

 [[[[[ ~/workspace/spt ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

Now I want to see the output in Eclipse console, so I create "External Tools Configurations" and have:

[image]

Also I add the PATH:

[image: environment - add mrt to PATH]

However when I try to run I get the following output in console:

> [1m[37mStand back while Meteorite does its thing[39m[22m
>
> [1m[37mDone installing smart packages[39m[22m
>
> [32mOk, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor![39m
>
> /home/alex/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/2d8b41a87cec884489ead138b5dfea31487363f3/meteor:
>   line 7: uname: command not found Sorry, this OS is not supported.

**Any ideas on what's going on?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somehow when it says *Append* its a loose definition. If meteor can't find `uname` it means path has been emptied to `/usr/lib/meteor/bin`. You could create a complete path variable manually:

Find out your path, run `echo $PATH` in your terminal, and add your `:/usr/lib/meteor/bin` to it and use this as your path in that dialog in the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's actually correct. I assumed that "append" would, well, "append" to each variable if it can find it. `${env_var:PATH}:/usr/lib/meteor/bin` solved my problem